# JavaScript 2D array lookup extremly slow

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2D array (500 x 500) in JavaScript to store a game map, when I loop through al the elements it takes no time. But when I introduce this line

```
let cell = map[i][j];
```

This takes so much time since it has to look up 250000 indexes in total, The loop takes 40 milliseconds to complete instead of near zero when you dont look any indexex up at al, how could I speed up this process?

EDIT:

I didn't explain my array very well so here is more information

```
var map = new Array(500); 
for (var i = -500 / 2; i < 500 / 2; i ++) { 
   map[i] = new Array(500); 
}
```

This is used to create the map, when I wanna place a stone at 30, 10 I can just use `map[30][10] = 4` (4 is the ID of a stone)

```
for (let i = -500 / 2; i < 500 / 2; i ++) {
   for (let j = -500 / 2; j < 500 / 2; j ++) {
      cell = map[i][j];
```

Is used to loop through the array and than I can check if the index contains a object and if the player should collide with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Could you elaborate more, please?

Comment: Yeah, where's the loop?

Comment: `let cell = map[i][j];` `<--` that's fast.  Can you explain a little more?

Comment: What are you doing that requires looping over the entire array? 250,000 iterations of anything is going to be slow.

Comment: @Barmar To check if your colliding with any object on the map

Comment: Shouldn't you only need to check locations near the object, not all locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be due to your use of negative indexes.

Javascript arrays are essentially objects, and array indexes are just properties whose keys are integers. However, they're optimized to handle the normal case where these are sequential integers starting from `0` -- these are stored in sequential memory, similar to the way arrays are implemented in traditional languages like C.

When you access an array index that isn't a non-negative index, it's treated as a normal object property. This is much less efficient than normal array indexing, it requires converting the index to a string and hashing it.

If you want to treat the arrays as having indexes from `-250` to `249`, add `250` to `i` and `j` before using them as indexes:

```
var map = new Array(500); 
for (var i = -500 / 2; i < 500 / 2; i ++) { 
   map[i+250] = new Array(500); 
}
for (let i = -500 / 2; i < 500 / 2; i ++) {
   for (let j = -500 / 2; j < 500 / 2; j ++) {
      cell = map[i+250][j+250];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `map[i+250][j]+250` be `map[i+250][j+250]`?

Comment: Yes! Only using positive indexes makes the delay only 1 to 3 milliseconds.